# SQL Statement with CASE when there are no values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, case

I am trying to use `CASE` statement for the following, however it is not getting desired results.

What I would like to have is if there are no values based on where condition, then I would like to return `'N'` as the result.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN  'N' else val END
from (select  nvl(is_expired,'x')val
  FROM test
 WHERE product_no = '12DF')
```

When product_no 12DF doesn't exist in table, I would like to return a value instead of empty or null.

Table structure is specified [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ac72/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no products '12DF', then you won't get any lines from your subselect.

I'm not quite sure which problem you want to solve. 
If you have embedded this in a program, because you can get a result set containing more than one row, that code should be able to handle an empty set as well.
If you expect zero or one lines in your result set, you can use an aggregate function like `max`.

```
select nvl(max(is_expired), 'N')
  from test
 where product_no = '12DF';
```